# ASP.NET cache memory saving code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a site view counter for my `ASP.NET-4.0 MVC-4` website. For this, what I am doing is:

I am storing the User's IP address in `asp.net cache`. And when the cache expired, I will do a bulk entry in my SQL Server Database.

Now for this I have to write a code which will insert the user's IP address in the cache memory. Initially I decided to write that code in my `/Home/Index Action` but then I thought if user visit my website's contact page directly and than leave my website without going to my website's home page then that user's IP address will not record in cache memory.

Now the obvious solution for this problem is that we can write a function and put a call to that function in My home and contact action and every other action. But I want something by which we can avoid writing function call at every place.

Can anybody please suggest me a good solution for this ?

Comment: Create BaseController and derive all Controller from BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "cache", not "catch"?

I also think you want one place that runs on every request, instead of having to put code in every controller.

In that case, you should look at adding to your Global.asax an event for Application_BeginRequest.

Comment: thanks and sorry for typo, when we deploy our website on server than also for every request to the website runs the Global.asax event ?

Comment: Correct - each managed request will also run the Application_BeginRequest method.